# How do I check for the existence of a character in a Linq query on a CSV file?

Tags: c#, linq, csv

I have a query which gets an employees number from a field containing their username and employee number in a field like this:

> name [employee number]

e.g.

> Fred Bloggs [1234]

My query works fine most of the time, but occasionally the field does not contain the employee number, and hence it throws an "index out of range" exception. (i.e. if the field just contains "Fred Bloggs" it will fail.)

The query is as follows:

```
var allEmpNos = (from row in csvTable.AsEnumerable()
                 join d in DeltekList
                 on row.Field<string>("Phone number") equals d.Mobile into t
                 from rt in t.DefaultIfEmpty()
                 select new
                 {
                   name = row.Field<string>("User name"),
                   empNo = rt == null ? row.Field<string>("User name").Split('[')[1].Replace("]", "") : rt.EmpNo,
                  });
```

How can I handle the "bad data" at run time? My ideal would be for it to throw an exception telling the user to correct the CSV file. I could do this by parsing the CSV twice, once to check the presence of a "[" and "]" and then again to do the actual import, but this seems inefficient as the CSV is pretty big.

Answer (score 1):

You could change your condition to something like this..

```
empNo = rt == null ? ( row.Field<string>("User name").Contains("[")?
                       row.Field<string>("User name").Split('[')[1].Replace("]", "")
                       :"--Invalid data--" )
                   : rt.EmpNo,
```

This way, you have all your incorrect formats in the collection. After this line of code, you could check if there are any items in collection with ""--Invalid data--" as empNo. You can give UserName as reference to users so that they can correct their data.

Optionally, you could also return your whole `row.Field<string>("User name")` appended with some hardcode text like `--ERROR`. This will help you capturing even the incorrect data.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a let clause and check the Length of the string array before you try to access index 1. This is indeed untested but it should give you the idea:

```
var allEmpNos = (from row in csvTable.AsEnumerable()
             join d in DeltekList
             on row.Field<string>("Phone number") equals d.Mobile into t
             from rt in t.DefaultIfEmpty()
             let arr = row.Field<string>("User name").Split('[')
             select new
             {
                 name = row.Field<string>("User name"),
                 empNo = rt == null ? ((arr != null && arr.Length > 1) ? arr[1].Replace("]", "") : string.Empty) : rt.EmpNo,
             });
```